# No primordial pool in 2012R2 on AWS with EBS disks

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to experiment with storage pools on Amazon's new 2012R2 AMI.

I've created several EBS volumes and attached them to the instance.   In the Server Manager I brought them online and initialized them, but no Primordial Pool is created.

[image: Server Manager - Disks]

[image: Server Manager - Storage Pools]

Is storage pools broken on AWS? Seems the disks meet all the requirements.  They are all over 4GB and SCSI disks.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I got it to work:

http://aws.amazon.com/windows/server2012r2/faq/
says:

---

Q: Can I create a Storage Space using an EBS volume?

Yes. EBS volumes can be used to setup a Storage Pool. The volumes can be formatted as NTFS or ReFS depending upon your application*.

*This is currently only supported on Windows Server 2012 and is not yet supported on Windows Server 2012 R2 running in AWS

---

I then had shutdown my R2 instance and detached my EBS drives.  I then launched a new Server 2012 (non-R2) instance, attached my drives and then the storage pool option was available!

Hope this helps someone else!

-Chad